# Why does natural deduction get its name?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, formal-systems

For example, I want to prove $\psi$ from the assumption $\{\varphi,\varphi\to\psi\}$ , the "most natural" proof would be:

$\varphi$

$\varphi\to\psi$

$\psi$(MP)

But using natural deduction, I must write the following sequence:

1. $\varphi\vdash\varphi$ (Ref)
2. $\varphi,\varphi\to\psi\vdash\varphi$ (+,1)
3. $\varphi\to\psi\vdash\varphi\to\psi$ (Ref)
4. $\varphi,\varphi\to\psi\vdash\varphi\to\psi$ (+,3)
5. $\varphi,\varphi\to\psi\vdash\psi$ ($\to$-,2,4)

This does not look "natural" at all. I cannot write a formula alone on a line. Every line is of the form: $\sum_i\vdash A_i$. Many logic books use this kind of proof system.
My "most natural" proof looks like a Hilbert proof system, but Hilbert proof system was considered not natural thus natural deduction system was invented.

Did I misunderstand  natural deduction proof system, or use natural deduction in a wrong way?

Comment: Yikes! Looking up Wikipedia entry, I am astounded at what some call "natural deduction." Your alternative was more like what I think of natural deduction. I would add line numbers, and cite the rule used for each line with pointers to previous lines as required. Finally, I would discharge the assumptions on lines 1 and 2 to obtain, A→((A→B)→B).

Comment: The name originated with [the people that developed the technique](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#SH11.a) and it is really "more natural", being a systematization of the traditional mean of proving theorems in mathematics.

Comment: You seem to be confusing features of the layout with the more essential stuff. Your natural deduction-style proof could easily be a Hilbert-style proof and vice versa if we just modify our layout conventions and interchange the terms"MP" with "$\to$ elimination". To see the difference everyone's talking about, try a proof whose natural deduction version involves $\to$-introduction. For example,  the proof from scratch of $\varphi\to \varphi$ can be a bit silly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_of_a_proof_in_a_classical_propositional_calculus_system

Comment: Not necessary to use a "verbose" style like that above... Line 5 will be enough: a single application of $(\to \text E)$ rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, let's consider the simple tautology $(B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$.  This just says if $B$ implies $C$ and $A$ implies $B$, then you can compose the two and conclude $A$ implies $C$.

For a Hilbert style proof: for clarity, A1 will be the axiom schema $A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A)$ and A2 will be the axiom schema $(A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$.

1. A2: $((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))))\rightarrow(((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)))\rightarrow((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))))$.
2. A1: $((A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)))\rightarrow((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))))$.
3. A2: $(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$.
4. MP on 2 and 3: $(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)))$.
5. MP on 1 and 4: $((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)))\rightarrow((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)))$.
6. A1: $(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))$.
7. MP on 5 and 6: $(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$.

Awful, right?  And this was one I selected for being one of the easiest cases with a lot of coincidental optimizations available, to reduce the amount I would have to type.  If for example you had reversed the hypotheses and wanted to prove $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$, then things wouldn't have worked out even this nicely.

And for that matter, why accept A1 and A2 as axioms in the first place?  Yes, you can give informal arguments for why each is true, but those arguments suggest that there should be a more reasonable way to prove things.

Now as for the natural deduction proof:

1. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B, A \vdash A\rightarrow B$: assumption.
2. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B, A \vdash A$: assumption.
3. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B, A \vdash B$: ${\rightarrow}E$ on 1 and 2.
4. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B, A \vdash B\rightarrow C$: assumption.
5. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B, A \vdash C$: ${\rightarrow}E$ on 4 and 3.
6. $B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow B \vdash A\rightarrow C$: ${\rightarrow}I$ on 5.
7. $B\rightarrow C \vdash (A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$: ${\rightarrow}I$ on 6.
8. $\vdash (B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$: ${\rightarrow}I$ on 7.

If you read this from bottom to top (mostly) and then from 1 through 5 top to bottom, this more closely reflects how we would informally argue that the formula is a tautology: if you assume $B\rightarrow C$, then you assume $A\rightarrow B$, then you furthermore assume $A$, then from the last two you can conclude $B$, and then combining with the first hypothesis, you can also conclude $C$.  Therefore, if you know $B\rightarrow C$ and $A\rightarrow B$, you can conclude $A\rightarrow C$.  As a result, if you know $B\rightarrow C$, then you also know $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$; and therefore, the given formula is a tautology as we wanted to show.

(It does seem that your formulation of natural deduction doesn't have "assumption" as a primitive proof rule, and instead forces you to start with the proof rule R and then add the unused hypotheses.  Still, this is a minor point and when you want to extract an assumption from the context, it's straightforward to make this argument.  It doesn't fundamentally result in an exponential explosion of the proof length and unreadable intermediate terms, the way that proofs in a Hilbert style system tend to do - once you've expanded any uses of the Deduction Theorem.  And proofs in a Hilbert system using the Deduction Theorem tend to look much closer to a natural deduction type of proof in practice, anyway -- so at that point, why not just use a natural deduction system in the first place?)

Comment: I think in the natural deduction proof, the antecedent on the left side of ⊢ on every line dazzles me. If getting rid of them, the proof looks more natural. I see other types of natural deduction, which list formulas without ⊢ on every line. But logic books seem to like   ∑i⊢Ai form of natural deduction. Is there some advantage of using this form? I think maybe this complex form of natural deduction can avoid drawing vertical lines in front of sub-proofs, but not sure if it is equivalent with the  ⊢ free forms such as Fitch style?Is there a mechanical method to convert the ⊢ free form to this?

Comment: I think the advantage is: fundamentally, over the course of a natural deduction proof, you have a changing set of available assumptions (the context).  Listing exactly how that changes at each point makes it clear what's going on; and it's also easier to work with for purposes of formalizing formal logic.  Yes, Fitch style systems can result in a more compact listing; but then you have to explain what the indentation means, the rules for how it's done, and the rules for how to use it (e.g. to use an assumption, you have to be in a block indented as a child of that assumption).

Comment: But yes, the Fitch style systems are equivalent to the formulations where at each line you explicitly list the context and the conclusion.  For example, given a Fitch proof, for each line you can list the assumptions that are "parents" of that line and put them to the left of a $\vdash$, and then if necessary reorganize the linear form into a tree form by looking at what previous lines are used and making them children in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not "The Natural Deduction System", rather it is "*A* Natural Deduction System".

Natural Deduction proof systems are those with many *Rules of Inference* and few *Axiomatic Schema* (preferably none), where the justification **for those rules** are based on "natural reasoning processes about the logical connectives".  They are simple, easy to follow instructions, that may have a tendency to build bulky proofs of even obvious statements.

The other category of proof systems are "Axiomatic", which have many "Axiom Schema" and few "Rules of Inference" (usually just one: modus ponens).  Hilbert's system is *an* axiomatic system.

Comment: Yes, this is just one form of the natural deduction system. But I prefer those ⊢free ones(only listing a formula on every line and annotation for the rule used). I am wondering why this complex style exists. Are there essential differences between the styles of  natural deduction system, or they are just different layouts(some are written more easily than others)?

Answer (score 0):

In Hilbert-style proofs,  the order in which the formulae of the proof are presented is ambiguous. Also, in order to make it readable, you need annotations. I just presented two problems that natural deduction systems don't have. As for the name, it stems not from the fight of who has the better proof writing system, but from historical reasons. As a last point, since they are just writing systems, formalities to make our life easier, it really comes down to preference.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Natural deduction models the thought process whereby we make provisional assumptions and then later "discharge" them to conclude an assertion that embraces the provisional assumptions. E.g., we might provisionally assume the existence of positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 = 2b^2$ and derive a contradiction and then discharge our assumptions to conclude that there are no positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 = 2b^2$. Hilbert-style systems impose a much less natural way of going about such a proof.

Comment: Yes I prefer ND as well. For me the biggest problem is the ambiguity, since you can't really treat a Hilbert-style proof as an object, some of the information that it should be carrying, is only there with annotations.